# http://IP:8080/i//reports/output/fileName.xls is downloading but same http://IP:8080/i//reports/output/fileName.xlsx is opening

Tags: html, excel

For link http://IP:8080/i/reports/output/fileName.xls, file is downloading, 
but for http://IP:8080/i/reports/output/fileName.xlsx file is opening in new tab.
I want to download the file in both cases.
Please help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: May be you must have set 'Open' as default for '.xlsx' file types in your browser. Did you try it in any other browser?